# How do I change the IP address and hostname on Solaris?

Tags: ip, solaris, hostname

I found lots of Web sites with answers via Google but they referred to changing several files, some of which don't exist. I edited all the files (using Linux experience as my guide) and rebooted but Solaris simply ignores the settings.

I also tried configuring the machine via smc, but while it allowed me to rename the computer and change its IP address, those changes didn't have an actual effect and didn't survive a reboot.

This is SunOS 5.10 Generic_139556 on x64.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I got it.

I edited the following files:

/etc/hosts
/etc/inet/netmasks
/etc/resolv.conf
/etc/nodename
/etc/hostname.

And I deleted this file:

/etc/dhcp.

That did it.

Weird!

Comment: Note that one might also need to change /etc/defaultrouter for the gateway configuration.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `/etc/nodename` stores the system's basic idea of its own name.

`/etc/hostname.<interface>` configures the network interface of that name; Solaris during boot-time enumerates those files and configures each interface based on information in there.  If you use names, rather than numeric IP addresses, in those files they must be defined in `/etc/hosts`.  What's in each file is put into an `ifconfig <interface> <parameters>` command.  By default it's just an IP address or a domain name, and the defaults are taken for things like netmask (from `/etc/inet/netmasks`.)  However, you can place things like netmasks, MTUs, etc. directly in those files, though it's not best practices to do so if there's a better method.

DHCP is configured for an interface if there's a `/etc/dhcp.<interface>` file.  If you don't want DHCP any more, get rid of them.

Default route is set in `/etc/defaultrouter`.  NIS domain, if used, is in `/etc/defaultdomain`, with ancillary configuration in `/var/yp`.

Name service priority is set in `/etc/nsswitch.conf`, but if you're not using NIS or LDAP or whatever, you probably don't have to change it.  DNS configuration is in the standard UNIX location of `/etc/resolv.conf`.

If you're running IPv6 there's more, but I took the assumption you weren't.

Answer (score 1):

The last time I administered a Solaris box was on Solaris 8, so I am not sure if this is still valid...but, there was a command "sys-unconfig" that would wipe out all the host-specific information like name, timezone and IP address.  It would then shutdown the system and when you rebooted would step you through the setup as if it were a newly installed box.

Comment: Solaris 10 has a programm named smc (Solaris Management Console) which connects to a computer and configures it. Except that it doesn't.

Comment: Yes, sys-unconfig is the "official" way to do this.  However, it wipes out a bunch more stuff which might be a pain in the behind.